# A complicated situation while using dlsym casting

Tags: c, dlsym

In our code there is a function defined as:

a.h

```
extern int (*get_prof_action(void))(void);
```

a.c

```
static int (*ProfAction)(void) = NULL;

int (*get_prof_action(void))(void)
{
    return ProfAction;
}
```

Then later in main.c, I want to gain this function through dlsym(I have to), so I used like this.

```
...
int (*p_get_prof_action(void))(void);
...

void my_function(){

...
void *handle=dlopen(mylibrary,RTLD_LAZY);
p_get_prof_action = (int (*(void))(void)) dlsym(handle,"get_prof_action");
...

}
```

And I got compile error:

```
error: cast specifies function type at line
(int (*(void))(void)) dlsym(handle,"get_prof_action");
=======================================================
```

Here are my questions:

1. This is not my code and I never saw such usage to define a function. Could you let me know what is this?
2. How do I correctly get this p_get_prof_action?

Thanks very much. This really stucks me a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `p_get_prof_action` as a function, not a function pointer.  The correct declaration would be:

```
int (*(*p_get_prof_action)(void))(void);
```

And the correct cast would be:

```
p_get_prof_action = (int (*(*)(void))(void)) dlsym(handle,"get_prof_action")
```

When dealing with function pointers, a `typedef` can be very helpful.  The function in question is returning a function pointer, so let's make one for the return type:

```
typedef int (*action)(void);
```

Then declare your function pointer to return that type:

```
action (*p_get_prof_action)(void);
```

And assign to it like this:

```
p_get_prof_action =  (action (*)(void))dlsym(handle,"get_prof_action");
```

Comment: This is great!! I have verified the answer, and it did resolved my problem. Again, thanks a lot. I never expected such quick and pretty answer. Have a good day dbush!